# Compact sets of compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces,$X$ not compact and $Y$ metric, denote with $C(X,Y)$ the set of continuous functions between $X$ and $Y$ and put on $C(X,Y)$ the compact-open topology.

My question is: **which are the compact sets of this topology?**

My guess is that each set of the form $\mathcal{K}:=\{f\in C(X,Y)| f(K_1)\subset K_2\}$ (where $K_1\subset X$ and $K_2\subset Y$ are compact sets) is compact, due to the fact that the sets of the form $\{f\in C(X,Y)| f(K_1)\subset U\}$ ($U\subset Y$ is compact) are a subbase for the topology and so for every open cover of $\mathcal{K}$ I can find a finite subcover. Am I right? are there other types of compact sets?

Thank you

Comment: The Arzelà-Ascoli theorem answers this in the case where $Y$ is metric and $X$ is compact.